# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails creating user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement  `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` and create a unblocked and enabled user.

Reading the documentation is not so clear [UserDeatails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html), what are the right settings for active user(not blocked, expired etc...), tried -

```
@Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
```

And got `org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException: User account has expired` and other variations ended with blocked.

Comment: Well, just look at the exception and your configuration please. It is clear that isAccountNonExipired has to return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default settings is that it will use [DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4ff51491d778fad40425163129f4dc945ee25e96/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L350) and [DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4ff51491d778fad40425163129f4dc945ee25e96/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L378) for checking `UserDetails` status in the following order:

```
  isAccountNonLocked()      = false , throw "User account is locked" exception.
  isEnabled()               = false , throw "User is disabled" exception.
  isAccountNonExpired()     = false , throw "User account has expired" exception.
  isCredentialsNonExpired() = false , throw "User credentials have expired" exception.
```

So , in order to pass all of these default checks , `UserDeatails` should return true for all the above methods.